# Dual Monitors when docked for Lenovo Y580

Tags: laptop

How can I set up a new laptop so that when its on my desk at home I can have it output to two lcd monitors?  Is there a particular docking station I need or some other way to set that up?

I have Lenovo Y580 with nvidia Geforce GTX 440m.

Edit: This laptop does appear to have Intel Wireless Display (WiDi), I'm just not sure how to take advantage of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a USB video card to connect to the other monitor.  Seems to work well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

On the side of your Laptop you should a HDMI port, that will give you access to an extra monitor. You could use a HDMI splitter cable giving output for two monitors.

Comment: Will HDMI out provide two independent output sources?

Comment: No it will only clone your laptop screen.  I  see that your laptop also has a VGA  port as well, although your  laptop would recognize both VGA and HDMI at the same time you would only be able to use two at a time (laptop plus VGA or  laptop plus HDMI) and also WiDi is for streaming to a TV.

Comment: Hmm I thought I had seen some one using WiDi for monitors as well.  Perhaps I didn't see it right.

Comment: There might be a couple of monitors out there that support WiDi, but you will still have the issue of it cloning not extending.